# Broadcast Receiver не работает через манифест

Tags: java, android

Broadcas tReceiver не работает через манифест

```
        <receiver android:name=".CallReciever" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Код

```
    public class CallReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.e("asd", "DA");
    }
}
```

Но при выключеннии и включении ничего не работает.

Но если убрать в манифесте строчки и добавить это

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        registerReceiver(new CallReciever(), new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        unregisterReceiver(new CallReciever());
    }
}
```

Зачем тогда на офф сайте выложили код для манифеста? если он бесполезный

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не знаю на каком таком офф сайте вы нашли код для манифеста, но в офф документации (http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SCREEN_ON) ясно написано что из манифеста этот Action ловить нельзя:

> You cannot receive this through components declared in manifests, only by explicitly registering for it with `Context.registerReceiver()`.

Comment: Это типо исключение? тобишь на другие Action работает?

Comment: Да, для большинства Action работает, но есть не мало исключений, о которых пишут в описании конкретного Action